# Skip weekends in angular 2 Highcharts from xaxis

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I have problem to skip weekends in highcharts in my angular 2 application. I have seen in highstock there is option ordinal:true to skip weekends but its not working for me. Is there any alternative to skip weekends. This works well from Tuesday on wards.

```
xAxis: {
                            type: "datetime",
                            tickInterval: this.tickinterval,
                            //ordinal: true,
                            breaks: [{
                                from: this.fromdate,
                                to: this.todate,
                                repeat: this.repeat
                            }],
                            labels: {
                                formatter: function () {
                                    return highcharts.dateFormat('%H', this.value);

                                }

                            },
                            plotLines: this.plotlines,


                            max: this.maxdate,
                        },

<chart [options]="chartOptions" type="chart" class="chartstyle" style="height:50%"> </chart>
```

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with using breaks? What is it not doing that you want to do?

Comment: It does not problem with breaks here i have to show previous day and current day between these i have used breaks. I just want to remove weekends. Sorry if understood wrong.

Comment: I don't think I am understanding what you are after. That said, you can use breaks to skip weekends.

Comment: Now i understood what you mean let me try http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/intraday-breaks/

Comment: I have tried weekend breaks but it is not working do i have any alternative `{ // Weekends
                                from: Date.UTC(2018, 2, 2, 23),
                                to: Date.UTC(2018, 2, 4, 23),
                                repeat: 7 * 24 * 36e5
                            }`

Comment: Hard to say, can you post a fiddle with your code where the issue can be seen?

Comment: Its difficult to create angular project in fiddle for me. But here i tried with Stackbiltz, again i have error that 'require' is not a function for angular2-highcharts integration so you can easily understand what is going on . https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w5n3uo

Comment: I think that the first thing we need to determine is what's the source of problem: Highcharts configuration or Angular. Could you provide a simplified demo in pure Highcharts? I see that you're using `angular2-highcharts` which isn't an official wrapper - maybe it's bugged.